# Missing error messages when rendering to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, rspec3

Im developing an API and when trying to make RSpec request tests pass I ran into a strange behaviour/error. When trying to save an empty record through `rails console` i get the error messages including the missing association error.

```
2.3.3 :006 > Breed.create().errors.messages
 (0.2ms)  begin transaction
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => {:specie=>["must exist"], :name=>["can't be blank"]}
```

But when rendering the error to json in the controller the association error disappears if I don't include the empty parameter when trying to create it from the API. 
Can someone help me understand why this is happening? Thanks.

app/spec/requests/breeds_spec.rb

```
describe 'PUT/PATCH #update' do
  context 'when not successfull' do
    before { patch breed_path(breed_id), params: { breed: { name: '' } } }

    it "renders the errors on why the record could not be updated" do
      puts json
      expect(json['errors']).to have_key('name')
      expect(json['errors']).to have_key('specie')
    end
  end
end
# => {"errors"=>{"name"=>["can't be blank"]}}
# Failure/Error: expect(json['errors']).to have_key('specie')
```

app/controllers/breeds_controller.rb

```
...
def create
  @breed = Breed.new(breed_params)
  if @breed.save
    render json: @breed, status: :created, location: @breed
  else
    render json: { errors: @breed.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
...
```

app/models/breeds.rb

```
# == Schema Information
# Table name: breeds
#
#  name       :string
#  specie_id  :integer
class Breed < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :specie
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

To sum up, the question is why when saving an empty record through rails console the error looks like `=> {:specie=>["must exist"], :name=>["can't be blank"]}` and when rendering the error to json its missing the association error `=> {"errors"=>{"name"=>["can't be blank"]}}`

Comment: I'd always use `required: true/false` on your relation, to declare it clearly what you expect. So in your case `belongs_to :specie, required: true`

Comment: That is correct, always declare your expectations, makes better code. But it doesnt explain my question...

Answer (score 0):

> In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is
>   required to have the associated record present by default.

see this [thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937)

If you want it to be optional

```
belongs_to :specie, optional: true
```